# read vcf file using ez vcard library

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

i am trying to read vcf file using ez vcard library and show all name and phone numbers in text view this is my code

```
        try{
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mark/Contact/a.vcf");
            List<VCard> vcards = Ezvcard.parse(file).all();
    for (VCard vcard : vcards){ 
            String name = vcard.getFormattedName().getValue();

            for (Telephone tel : vcard.getTelephoneNumbers()){
                System.out.println(tel.getTypes() + ": " + tel.getText());


                    TextView tv1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

                    tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            tv1.setText(name);


            }}      

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: what issue are you facing? 
it is already answered here, https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

Comment: i need any way to read vcf file from internal storage and show vcf file names and numbers in listview.. have u any example?

Comment: i search many library but no one working.. i need any example.. i am new in java

Comment: have you checked this : https://github.com/aarsy/vcard-androidParser? many more are available. please check on google with right keyword.